# Android Studio Import popup not showing

Tags: android-studio

I've search the Internet but couldn't find the answer.

When I enter a class that's not imported yet, let's say `List`, normally Android Studio shows a blue popup asking if I want to import it by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That popup is gone and I don't know why. In the settings the "Show import popup" is checked but still doesn't show up.

Any ideas how to make it show up again?

Comment: Make sure `Editor > General > Auto Import > Add unambiguous imports on the fly` is checked off - this setting will skip the import dialog, if there is only one possible class to import.

Comment: @DarekKay, doesn't make a difference if it's checked or not. The popup still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer so I had to resort to uninstalling Android Studio and install it again.
Very important: After uninstall go to your personal folder and delete all the folders related to Android Studio's settings because even if you check "Delete my personal settings" in the uninstaller, it won't delete them.