# Why Android Studio doesn't Auto Import the correct package android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have the following setting for **Auto Import** in **Android Studio** V2.0 and I created a new Fragment class as follows

```
import android.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

// some code
}
```

[image]

But when I tried to use it in a FragmentPagerAdapter as below

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MyFragment1(); //error here
        case 1:
            return new MyFragment2(); //error here
    }
}
```

I receive this error:

> Incompatible types. Found: 'com.example.android.viewpager.MyFragment1', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Of course, when I change the import on MyFragment1 from `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` the error will disappear

My question is : Why didn't Android Studio import the correct package automatically?
Is it a bug in Android Studio or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The package names are alphabetical when you go to import the class.

It simply resolves the first one it finds.

[image]

You should have the "Show import popup" option enabled if you want it to give you the option on which one to use.

[image]

Comment: That seems logical but I have another problem. I checked the "Show import popup" but it doesn't show and still do the automatic import.
This problem has been reported before
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30280289/6180768

Comment: Not sure. I don't typically trust the automatic import for classes of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to first type `Fragment` when the popup shows up just ignore it by pressing escape key. Once you are done typing, press `Alt + Enter` (the mouse cursor should be over Fragment) , now it will show the popup with two import options, here you can choose the one which you want.

While pressing Alt + Enter it will import automatically without any popup if there is only `one possible` import available.